# Проблема с открытием Google Play аутентификации

Tags: android, unity3d, google-play, google-play-services

При старте приложения, появляется подключение и сразу пропадает, без уведомления сверху что пользователь подключен, в логах и Logcat выбивает Initialization failed, Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой? и как вы ее решали

P.S. Подключение к интернету есть, проверял на двух смартфонах, и в Nox

Использую версию GooglePlayGamesPlugin-0.9.42
Unity 5.6.1.f1
Билд в Gradle
используемый код подключения:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using GooglePlayGames;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;
public class GooglePlayManager : Accessible<GooglePlayManager> {

private void Start () 
{
    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate ();
    Social.localUser.Authenticate ((bool success) => {
        if(success) 
            MonoBehaviour.print("Initialization was successful.");
        else 
            MonoBehaviour.print("Initialization failed.");

    });
}
```

Ошибки:

> [Play Games Plugin DLL] 12/07/17 17:53:51 +02:00 DEBUG: Activating
>   PlayGamesPlatform.
>
> [Play Games Plugin DLL] 12/07/17 17:53:51 +02:00 DEBUG: Instance was
>   not initialized, using default configuration.
>
> [Play Games Plugin DLL] 12/07/17 17:53:51 +02:00 WARNING: Creating new
>   PlayGamesPlatform
>
> [Play Games Plugin DLL] 12/07/17 17:53:56 +02:00 DEBUG: Starting Auth
>   Transition. Op: SIGN_IN status: ERROR_NOT_AUTHORIZED
>
> [Play Games Plugin DLL] 12/07/17 17:53:56 +02:00 DEBUG: Invoking
>   callbacks, AuthState changed from silentPending to Unauthenticated.

Comment: `PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;` добавьте, чтоб логи увидеть более полные.

Comment: Ошибки такого характера
`[Play Games Plugin DLL] 12/07/17 17:53:51 +02:00 DEBUG: Activating PlayGamesPlatform.

 [Play Games Plugin DLL] 12/07/17 17:53:51 +02:00 DEBUG: Instance was not initialized, using default configuration.

[Play Games Plugin DLL] 12/07/17 17:53:51 +02:00 WARNING: Creating new PlayGamesPlatform

 [Play Games Plugin DLL] 12/07/17 17:53:56 +02:00 DEBUG: Starting Auth Transition. Op: SIGN_IN status: ERROR_NOT_AUTHORIZED

[Play Games Plugin DLL] 12/07/17 17:53:56 +02:00 DEBUG: Invoking callbacks, AuthState changed from silentPending to Unauthenticated.`

Answer (score 0):

Решение: Использовался не правильный keystore, ключ проекта должен совпадать с ключом  приложения в google play console